# Animating an object inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Z2YSt/173/

the code :

```
function createShipMissil(x, y, imgw, imgh) {
            MissileCtx.save();
            MissileCtx.clearRect(0, 0, imgw, imgh);
            MissileCtx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
            MissileCtx.fillRect(x, y, imgw, imgh);
            MissileCtx.restore();
            y -= 1;
            setTimeout(function () { createShipMissil(x, y, imgw, imgh); }, 30);

        }
```

My problem is that when the line is drawn, it looks continuous. How can I change that to make it look like a rectangle moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
MissileCtx.clearRect(x, y, 1, 30);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2YSt/174/)**

Comment: is there a way to make it go a bit faster ?

Answer (score 1):

In general drawing to the canvas only ADDS new graphics - to do an animation you have to erase the background each frame. 
Specifically you need to have a draw function that is called repeatedly which:

1. Clears the canvas ( draw a big background colour rectangle or whatever backdrop you want)
2. Then draws all the objects that are moving.

Using a fixed time period (30ms as you do) has a variety of problems - once you get this to work look around stack overflow to figure out how to match this framerate to the browsers redraw cycle.

Comment: context.clear() or context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) if the previous doesn't exist.